# Python http server with multiple directories

Tags: python

Is it possible to add multiple variable paths in os.chdir method from two different directories like, var1 ='d:\\folder1' , var2 = 'e:\\folder2'? and then putting them in os.chdir(var1,var2).
I tried but could not join them, got a syntax error.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using symbolic links:
On windows, you can create symbolic links to directories as so:

```
mklink /D <symbolic link name> <destination directory>
```

So in a new folder you can run:

```
mklink /D folder1 "D:\folder1"
mklink /D folder2 "E:\folder2"
```

On linux this would be:

```
ln -s <destination directory> <symbolic link name>
```

```
ln -s /mnt/d/folder1 folder1 
ln -s /mnt/e/folder2 folder2
```

Then by running a python HTTP server in the directory, you can access both folders as sub-folders of the server:
[image: HTTP server file gui showing 2 folders]